# SPSS PROCESS - confusion about what how to test relationships

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interaction, spss

I am doing my first research and so have no experience in analysis, only theory. I have worked out how to test my moderator relationship using PROCESS model=1, however I am not sure how to test the other hypotheses in SPSS since it seems PROCESS is only for my H3?

IV = X; DV = Y; Moderator variable = W
All are continuous

H1: X is positively associated with Y
H2: X is positively associated with W
H3: W will positively moderate the effect of X on Y

What test is used for H1 and H2? For H2, is W treated as a DV?

I have two categorical covariates.

Updated:
These hypotheses are for a student research proposal. I have assumed that I need to show that X has an effect on Y (H1) and that it is strengthened by W (H3).
For H2, I am suggesting that W is an antecedent to X and so I need to test that.

Comment: Why do you need to evaluate H1 and H2? If there is a moderation/interaction in your situation, the association between Y and X will depend on the value of W. In that case there is no single association between Y and X; H1 thus isn't well defined.

Answer (score 0):

"Moderation" is just another name for an interaction term involving two (or more) predictors in a regression model. If there is "moderation" or "interaction," then there is no single measure of the association between either X or W and your outcome Y (in your terminology). The association of either one with Y depends on the value of the other. So your `H1`, the single-variable association between X and Y, isn't very meaningful if there is moderation.

The standard way to evaluate moderation is via the statistical significance of the interaction coefficient in the model. The sign of the interaction coefficient shows the direction of the moderation. I'm not familiar with SPSS, but I suspect that the PROCESS macro for testing `H3` provides that information.

There is no need in general for a moderator to be associated with its interacting predictor (your `H2`). If you want, you can test the association between your continuous predictors X and W via their correlation coefficient. In practice, a high correlation between X and W will tend to inflate the standard errors of both of their individual regression coefficients. That's a simple case of how a high [variance inflation factor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variance-inflation-factor) can pose problems with modeling.